# How to define textbox input as a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ascii, caesar-cipher

This is for a science project, which is due in a few months. Im a complete beginner and I really don't know whats wrong with this simple Caesar cipher program. Im using ascii to convert the characters to numbers, add a set number to that, then return the letter and repeat for each in the string. It works fine when I put in two set inputs, but when I use a textbox to gather input, it gives me weird symbols which aren't even included in the ascii table.

```js
var messages = document.getElementById("messages");
var shfBox = document.getElementById("shfBox");
var strBox = document.getElementById("strBox");
var button = document.getElementById("button");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var orgstr = strBox.value;
  var orgshf = shfBox.value;
  var str = orgstr;
  var shf = orgshf;
  var output = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var asciiValue = str[i].charCodeAt();
    if (asciiValue >= 65 && asciiValue <= 77) {
      output += String.fromCharCode(asciiValue + shf);
    } else if (asciiValue >= 78 && asciiValue <= 90) {
      output += String.fromCharCode(asciiValue - shf);
    } else if (asciiValue >= 97 && asciiValue <= 109) {
      output += String.fromCharCode(asciiValue + shf)
    } else if (asciiValue >= 110 && asciiValue <= 122) {
      output += String.fromCharCode(asciiValue - shf)
    } else {
      output += str[i];
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
  return output;
  return str;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>repl.it</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <ul id="messages"></ul>
  <div>
    <input id="strBox" type="text" style="padding: 10px;">
  </div>
  <div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <input id="shfBox" type="number" style="padding: 10px;">
  <div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button id="button" type="button" style="padding: 4px;">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <p id="output"></p>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I've added the JavaScript from your link to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that your addition in the `output += ...` is doing string concatenation, not numeric addition, because `orgshf` is a string. Just replace:

```
var orgshf = shfBox.value;
```

with

```
var orgshf = +shfBox.value;
```

And it instantly works much better, because the `+` operator here converts the values to numbers.

(You could also do:

```
var orgshf = Number(shfBox.value);
```

This does exactly the same as the above, and is preferred by many due to being more explicit. As I said, both do the same thing, and it comes down to personal preference - take your pick.)

It's still not perfect though, as sometimes your character codes are giving you non-alphabetical characters. You will also need to alter your ranges in the `if` statements so that they depend on `orgshf`. But I hope this is enough to allow you to fix it, because the main issue was that you were not adding numbers as you thought you were.